# 'Undefined variable' error: why?

Tags: vim9script, vim9

```
vim9script

set laststatus=2
set statusline=
var separator = '    '
set statusline+=%{expand('%:p')}
set statusline+=%{separator}
set statusline+=%l:%v
```

Error: `Undefined variable: separator`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim9 script `:var` is used to define a local variable that is not visible outside. Specify global scope `g:` directly or remove `vim9script` command as it is not doing much here anyway.

Also to note that creating "long separator" by hardcoding some arbitrary number of spaces is usually a horrible idea. Prefer `%=` and `%<` whenever it makes sense.

Comment: I suspect I need `%<` in my case. Could you show how to use it?

Comment: @johnc.j. Put percent-less before field to be truncated. By default this is the first one, i.e. too long file name. See how default status line works, for example.